# Deny access to fastboot

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

I'm searching a way to deny access to fastboot mode... I don't care if it will be deleted, just want to deny access but still be able to use the device.

I rooted my phone but I didn't find any files that called fastboot or something like that. Where the files are hidden?

I have an idea to use this command :
fastboot flash bootloader.
And flash a img that will show only a black screen, or maybe flash the boot.img, I don't know... Will it help? Someone have a better idea? Is it totally impossible?

I heard about people who had bugs in there fastboot... That exactly what I want!

I don't have a sumsung device, I have a rooted oneplus 5t and I don't care to damage it completely while trying to learn new stuff!

Some one ask my question too:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/is-it-possible-to-relock-bootloader-while-using-custom-rom-and-recovery.4072955/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124534/discussion-on-question-by-joe-deny-access-to-fastboot).